# Keras VGG16 preprocess_input modes

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, vgg-net, image-preprocessing

I'm using the [Keras VGG16 model](https://keras.io/applications/#vgg16).

I've seen it there is a [preprocess_input method to use in conjunction with the VGG16 model](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/vgg16.py).  This method appears to call the [preprocess_input method in imagenet_utils.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/imagenet_utils.py) which (depending on the case) calls [_preprocess_numpy_input method in imagenet_utils.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/imagenet_utils.py).

The `preprocess_input` has a `mode` argument which expects "caffe", "tf", or "torch".  If I'm using the model in Keras with TensorFlow backend, should I absolutely use `mode="tf"`?

If yes, is this because the VGG16 model loaded by Keras was trained with images which underwent the same preprocessing (i.e. changed input image's range from [0,255] to input range [-1,1])?

Also, should the input images for testing mode also undergo this preprocessing? I'm confident the answer to the last question is yes, but I would like some reassurance.

I would expect Francois Chollet to have done it correctly, but looking at https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/blob/master/vgg16.py either he is or I am wrong about using `mode="tf"`.

**Updated info**

@FalconUA directed me to the [VGG at Oxford](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/research/very_deep/) which has a **Models** section with links for the 16-layer model.  The information about the `preprocessing_input` `mode` argument `tf` scaling to -1 to 1 and `caffe` subtracting some mean values is found by following the link in the **Models** 16-layer model: [information page](https://gist.github.com/ksimonyan/211839e770f7b538e2d8#file-readme-md). In the Description section it says:

> "In the paper, the model is denoted as the configuration D trained with scale jittering. The input images should be zero-centered by mean pixel (rather than mean image) subtraction. Namely, the following BGR values should be subtracted: [103.939, 116.779, 123.68]."

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `mode` here is not about the backend, but rather about *on what framework the model was trained on and ported from.* In the [keras link](https://keras.io/applications/#vgg16) to VGG16, it is stated that:

> These weights are ported from the ones released by [VGG at Oxford](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/research/very_deep/)

So the VGG16 and VGG19 models were trained in Caffe and ported to TensorFlow, hence `mode == 'caffe'` here (range from 0 to 255 and then extract the mean `[103.939, 116.779, 123.68]`).

Newer networks, like *MobileNet* and *ShuffleNet* were trained on TensorFlow, so `mode` is `'tf'` for them and the inputs are zero-centered in the range from -1 to 1.

Comment: Thanks! That's the info I was looking for.  I guess I should have been more diligent in digging through the links.  So, is it always the case that models trained on TensorFlow have inputs zero-centered in range from -1 to 1?  If, yes, do you know why?  Similarly, is it always the case that models trained in caffe are in range 0 to 255 and then extract the mean?  I'm trying to figure out if these just happen to be how the models keras uses were trained or if this is suggested/recommended practice for the respective frameworks.

Comment: @user3731622 well, it is not always the case, it is just... a historical thing. You see, Caffe was the most popular in 2012-2016, so everything was trained on Caffe back then, and since BatchNormalization was not a thing at that time, it is common to see `-127.5 ... 127.5` values (VGG is indeed a very old network).

Comment: @user3731622 The newer architectures were using BatchNorm and other stuffs, and they found that it is generally good to keep the outputs around `-1 .. 1`, so the newer stuffs, like *Xception* and *MobileNet* were using that kind of normalization, and they were trained on the most popular frameworks, which are TensorFlow and PyTorch.

Answer (score 6):

In my experience in training VGG16 in Keras, the inputs should be from 0 to 255, subtracting the mean `[103.939, 116.779, 123.68]`. I've tried transfer learning (freezing the bottom and stack a classifier on top) with inputs centering from `-1` to `1`, and the results are much worse than `0..255 - [103.939, 116.779, 123.68]`.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to use VGG16 myself again lately, i had troubles getting descent results by just importing `preprocess_input` from vgg16 like this:

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16, preprocess_input
```

Doing so, preprocess_input by default is set to `'caffe'` mode but having a closer look at [keras vgg16 code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2.1.6/keras/applications/vgg16.py), i noticed that weights name

> 'https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.1/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5'

is referring to tensorflow twice. I think that preprocess mode should be `'tf'`.

```
processed_img = preprocess_input(img, mode='tf')
```